# Regex or on multiple/single characters

Tags: regex

I'm dynamically making a regex.

I want it to match the following:

```
lem
le,,m
levm
lecm
```

Basically, "lem" but before the m it can have any number of `,` or any one of any character.  Right now I have

```
le[\,]{0,}[.]?m
```

you can see it at
http://regexr.com?303ne

It should match every one but the third one.

**Update:** I figured it out:

```
le[\,]{0,}.?m
```

Comment: Can you describe which inputs match and which don't?

Comment: Okay, I added some input examples.

Comment: @LemonPie: What about "LemonPie"? Does that match or not? I.e., do the doubled-up characters have to be consecutive for the match to fail?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: See my RexExr link. It should match every one but the third one.

Comment: @LemonPie: thank link explains nothing

Comment: Your solution does not fit your specification and is unnecessarily complicated. See my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever you think "or" in Regular Expressions, you should start with alternation:

```
a|b
```

matches either `a` or `b`.  So

> any number of a list of characters OR 1 of any character

can be translated quite literally to

```
[...]*|.
```

where `...` would be the list of characters to match (a *character class*). If you use that as part of a longer expression, you need to use parentheses, because concatenation binds stronger (has higher precedence) than alternation:

```
le([,]*|.)m
```

Because the character class has only one item, we can simplify this:

```
le(,*|.)m
```

Note that `.` by default means "any character but newline".

Comment: just FYI - it is not polite to downvote the answers that answered the first revision of the question. It's not my fault that OP changed the question

Comment: @zerkms According to mobile interface, last update by OP was 1 hour ago. Last update by you was 59 minutes ago.

Comment: so I should have been F5 all the time to see if OP changes his mind? I've been answering the original question, getting the details one by one (and you know - it is not my fault that the original question and all other edits haven't contained all the necessary information in a moment), and in the very end I got downvote... perfect

Comment: `m` is an unnecessary pattern modifier here because there is no `^` or `$` anchor in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
le(,*|.?)m
```

it should do what you want.

Comment: `m` is an unnecessary pattern modifier here because there is no `^` or `$` anchor in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
([^,])(?=\\1)
```

But this does the opposite :-) Not sure if it is ok for you

**UPD**:

this should work for you:

```
~^(?:,|([^,])(?!\\1))+$~
```

not sure what dialect you're looking for, but it works in PCRE: http://ideone.com/6Q3Wk

**UPD2**:

**the same** regex included into another

```
$r = '(?:,|([^,])(?!\\1))+';
var_dump(preg_match('~le' . $r . 'm~', 'leem'));
```

In this case the final expression becomes: `le(?:,|([^,])(?!\\1))+m` where `le` and `m` are added around mine **without modifications**

Comment: That seems to match every character except a ,

Comment: @LemonPie: it does the opposite work. If you can inverse the result - then it fits the task perfectly

Comment: I don't believe it would work for my purposes as I'm making a profanity filter.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for still. See my RegExr link.  http://regexr.com?303ne It should match every one but the third one.

Comment: @LemonPie: why `leem` should match? You said: `suppose any number of , OR 1 of any character can match in the middle` and `does not match because e can only happen once`

Comment: Because I added a e before my regex.

Comment: @LemonPie: can you please modify your question so it contains the set of obvious requirements for string to be matched? For now I just cannot get what `Because I added a e before my regex` means :-S

Comment: Okay, I modified it. Hopefully I explained it better.

Comment: @LemonPie: `I want it to match the following:

lem le,,m levm lecm` --- and my regex matches them all: http://ideone.com/aZDo0

Comment: @LemonPie: You're "making a profanity filter"? Another one? Good luck with The Scunthorpe Problem!

Comment: Much too complicated and incompatible at no advantage.

Comment: @PointedEars: thanks for downvoting for the answer that is perfectly correct to the **original** question - the original was abstract one about arbitrary string and arbitrary characters in the middle

Comment: isn't (?:,|([^,]) equal to "dot"? (comma, or non-comma) why are you doing it that way?

Comment: @sweaver2112: there is a lookahead assertion after, so `(?:,|([^,])(?!\\1))` means - comma or any other character that is followed by some another character and it matches `,` and `ab`, but doesn't match `cc` (and that is what OP asked about in very first question revision)