# Regex for a set of different scenarios (first period with a complete word in front of it)

Tags: regex

I have a set of strings that can come in different formats. I want to be able to get everything from the first period and any of the chars (can be a space, bracket, curly brace etc) before the first period.

For example:

- `if SCHEMA.COLUMN = 'XYZ'` - should return `SCHEMA`
- `SUM(SCHEMA.COLUMN)` - should return `SCHEMA`
- `[SCHEMA.COLUMN]` - should return `SCHEMA`
- `select product_id decode (warehouse_id 'Apple','APPL', 'Microsoft', 'MSFT') from SCHEMA1.inventories a, SCHEMA2.quantity b where a.id = b.id` - multiple periods in this but should return `SCHEMA1`
- `select product_id decode (warehouse_id '.','APPL', 'Microsoft', 'MSFT') from SCHEMA1.inventories a, SCHEMA2.quantity b where a.id = b.id` - multiple periods in this but should return SCHEMA1

I am able to get the regex to return the string if there is one begin char but couldnt get multiple begin chars

```
\((.*?)\.
```

this is returning `SCHEMA` when the string is `SUM(SCHEMA.column)`

I was referring to some previous posts on this topic but couldnt succeed with those solutions

[Previous Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405965/regex-or-on-multiple-single-characters)

Can someone suggest how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP has changed problem to match dot excluding dots in quoted string. Moreover quotes can be escaped as well.

Here is the regex that may be used:

```
^.*?\b(\w+)\.(?=(?:[^'\\]*'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')*[^'\\]*$)
```

- `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` matches a quoted string ignoring escaped quotes in the string.
- `(?=...)` makes sure to match dot outside quoted string by asserting that we have 0 or more of fully quoted strings ahead of current position.

---

**Original Solution:**

You may use this regex and grab string from capture group #1:

```
^[^.]*\b(\w+)\.
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jwutPP/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^.]*`: Match 0 or more characters containing non-dot characters
- `\b`: word boundary
- `(\w+)`: Capture group #1 containing 1+ word characters
- `\.`: Match a dot

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/jwutPP/3)

Comment: Do you even need `^[^.]*`? The rest of the regexp matches the first word that's followed by `.`

Comment: @Barmar: It's not needed if `global` flag is not used but I don't know regex flavor OP  is using so not sure if global behavior can be turned off or not.

Comment: @anubhava - thank you - just curious, how can you specify to find a second or third period instead of the first period in a string just in case

Comment: @Prashanth: To find word just before 3rd dot use: `^(?:[^.]*\.){2}[^.]*\b(\w+)\.`

Comment: @anubhava This will fail if the `.` happens to occur in a string literal before the first occurrrence as a schema/object name separator. Replace `warehouse_id 'Apple'` by `warehouse_id '.'` in the 4th test string to see it

Comment: @collapsar: Ignoring dot in string literal is another problem that is not straight forward to handle using pure regex as quotes can also be escaped

Comment: @collapsar - nice catch !! I have updated the original question to include this scenario.

Comment: @anubhava - just edited - please let me know if this makes it clearer !

Comment: This does not correctly process `select product_id, 'x.y\\\'' whatever from SCHEMA1.inventories a, SCHEMA2.quantity b where a.id = b.id`, ie. a sequence of escaped escape symbol and escaped delimiter in a string literal. I do readily admit that this is a contrived example.

Comment: An example on which the revised version fails: `select product_id, 'x.y' whatever from SCHEMA1.inventories a, SCHEMA2.quantity b where a.id = b.id -- John's idea`, ie. a line comment following the code portion that contains a single delimiter

Comment: @collapsar: This regex *only* ignores dots in quoted string as per OP. Does your regex work with this input?

Comment: @anubhava: This regex matches `x` in the example string which it should not. The reason is the line comment at the end. My regex does not catch this, and neither does it catch any other `foo.bar` occurrence in literals preceding the first qualified name, as I stated in my answer. While your solution comes closer to being correct in general, it has the drawback of being next to unmaintainable.

Comment: @anubhava: The set of OP's 5 examples is correctly handled by mine (see [this Regex101 page](https://regex101.com/r/ew0v63/7/) and its predecessors). The advantage of your solution is independence of the support of the 'global' flag, however imho it comes at a very high cost.

Answer (score 1):

The following covers most (but not all) situations. It identifies the occurrence of an identifier followed by a `.` serving as a separator in a qualified name. The sought string is held in capture group #1.

```
\b(\w+)\.(?=[a-zA-Z_])
```

The problematic cases are preceding string literals that contain `.`. These should be skipped. Detecting and skipping string literals with a regex is complicated since in general you have to count matching delimiters and cater for escaped delimiters within a literal.

So this solution might suffice to serve your needs. It will fail if a part of a string literal matches `\w\.[a-zA-Z_]` but that usually does not happen: `.` in a punctuation role is usually followed by some non-letter ( eg. whitespace, delimiters ).

This solution will produce others but the first match if global behavior cannot be turned off in the regex engine.

[Demo (Regex 101)](https://regex101.com/r/Pvf7zV/1)

**Update**

The following regex does correctly skip over string literals preceding the first match of a qualified name's first match:

```
^[^']*?('[^\\']*((\\.)[^\\']*)*'[^']*?)*\b(\w+)\.(?=[a-zA-Z_])
```

The desired result is in capture group 4.

The pattern works by repeatedly matching an alternating sequence of literals and non-literals - the matched string starting with either of it - as a (possibly empty) prefix to the first qualified name. There is an obvious extension to 2 kinds of literal delimiters.

While the pattern works, I do advise to thoroughly consider alternative approaches to using it in production code, as it suffers badly in terms of maintainability.

[Demo (Regex 101)](https://regex101.com/r/vXIhTC/1)

Comment: We cannot simply rule out having string literals like `'foo.bar'`

Comment: @anubhava Depending on the application, we may be allowed to do just that. In general, we cannot, and that's why I wrote 'most (but not all) situations'. This solution has its limits but on the pro side is still somewhat maintainable.

Comment: I have encountered  `'foo.bar'` type of cases many times so it is not really out of world scenario.

Comment: @anubhava I've never claimed that it was an outlandish scenario.